# no module called numpy

Tags: ubuntu, numpy, installation, python-3.4

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and just installed python 3.4. 
And on terminal I entered:

sudo apt-get install python-numpy

sudo apt-get install cython

sudo apt-get install python-scipy

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

when I tried to run something on idle, it showed the massage:

line 1, in 
    import numpy as n
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

I don't know much about programming and i'm new to linux, but I think I either didn't install numpy at all or I installed it for a different version of python. What did I do wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Because what you did should install it for python 2.x